# How to specify the path which is to be tested using iozone?

Tags: benchmarking, freebsd, zfs, iozone

I have a freebsd install which has ufs filesystem. Inside freebsd i have created a zpool in raidz1. Now i want to perform iozone test on zfs but i am not able to understand how to specify that iozone test on the zpool not the base filesystem.

Comment: Personally, I just `cd /Volumes/ZFSPOOL ; iozone -A`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I personally use, which is also specifying the files to be used.

```
./iozone -R -l 16 -u 16 -r 128k -s 200G –F /testpool/g{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}
```

If you only want a single file to be used, just use -f instead of -F.